# Need assistance in Xamarin Development Environment setup

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have installed VS 2015 for the purpose of learning Xamarin Development. But, look what is happening is that I am not even getting right templates to create an Android application. Please find below the screenshot of my VS:

[image]

Now, Can anyone help me in getting my environment ready for android development at least. How can I find what are the things which are missing.

One more thing, previously I had android studio but now I have uninstalled it. So can I connect already downloaded android sdk with this VS Setup by putting sdk path at somewhere. I am just guessing if it is possible.

Anyway, I want my development environment ready. Suggest me.

Comment: Installation instructions: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/

Comment: Agree with @Feryal, Xamarin.com is a great source of information. This might be an installation issue. Did you install Update 3 of Visual Studio 2015? Did you check all Cross-Platform options specific to Xamarin for your installation?

Comment: May be you haven't checked the required options in visual studio. Follow the process : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt613162.aspx. Also check for proper installation of android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Like Himanshu mentioned in the comments. You may not have selected the Xamarin during the installation.

Follow the steps mentioned in the link here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt613162.aspx